# Is there a way I can make it so my web page always has a vertical scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a header on the top of my web site and links on that. Clicking on the links brings up new pages below.

Some of the pages have a lot of text and others just a small amount. The result is that some pages appear with a scroll bar and others without.  It looks very distracting to see the scroll bar appear and then not appear as I move from page to page.

Is there a way I can ensure there is always a vertical scroll bar present?

Comment: html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use overflow-y: scroll on whatever element you want to always have a scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CSS rule for this is `overflow` (also available as `-x` and `-y`)

`body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}`

Other values are for example `auto` (only when needed, default), `hidden` and `visible`.